# calculating time complexities

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Suppose we have the following algorithms:

```
i=0; j =N;
while (i < j){
  i++;
  j /= 2;
}
```

what is the time complexity of this algorithm? I figured the following but I am not sure if it is correct and how to formally prove it. Suppose we double $N$ we get only one more step so it is of order O(log (N)). However this is not really a rigorous proof. What is a good way to tackle this kind of problem in general? Thanks!

Comment: The number of iterations `j` is such that `j ~= N * 2^-j`. Solve for `j`.

Comment: That's exactly how you go about it. You calculate T(N). Having T(N+1) from T(N) gives you a proof by induction.

Comment: time complexity is log n

Comment: @lserni OP have T(2N) from T(N) but you are correct it is induction